# Django rest framework urls

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm structuring a Django API with rest framework, I read the docs and DRF only makes a crud (get, post, patch, delete) from a model. Now the deal is how I can make custom actions with DRF.

Example:

```
api/v1/model/custom_action
```

Code:

```
class DistrictViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      queryset = District.objects.all()
      serializer_class = DistrictSerializer

      def custom_action(request, param):
          # do many actions and return as Json Object
```

urls.py

```
url(r'api/v1/', include(router.urls))
```

Where router

```
router.register(r'model',api.ModelViewSet)
```

I'm correct with this or I need to create another modelview, customize the code and add it to router list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add custom actions as you have done but you may need the `@action` decorator to configure the url to apply to a single object, or many.
`@action(detail=True)` adds `pk` to the url, as it applies to one object.

The url is generated from the action name, so for example

```
@action(detail=True)
def custom_action(self):
    pass
```

Would yield the url `^<app_name>/{pk}/custom_action/$`

You may find this useful:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing

Comment: Thanks!! It worked. Reading the docs again to check if I miss some :D